# Is it possible to view a postgresql table using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

```
def connectxmlDb(dbparams):
conn_string = "host='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' port='{}'"\
.format(dbparams['HOST'], dbparams['DB'], dbparams['USERNAME'], dbparams['PASSWORD'], dbparams['PORT'])
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    pass
except Exception as err:
    print('Connection to Database Failed : ERR : {}'.format(err))
    return False
print('Connection to Database Success')
return conn



dbconn = connectxmlDb(params['DATABASE'])
```

The above mentioned is the code I use to connect to postgresql database

```
sql_statement = """ select a.slno, a.clientid, a.filename, a.user1_id, b.username, a.user2_id, c.username as username2, a.uploaded_ts, a.status_id
                    from masterdb.xmlform_joblist a
                    left outer join masterdb.auth_user b
                    on a.user1_id = b.id 
                    left outer join masterdb.auth_user c
                    on a.user2_id = c.id
                    """
cursor.execute(sql_statement)

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

This is my code to extract data from a postgres table using python.
I want to know if it is possible to view this data using Pandas

This is the code I used:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_statement, dbconn)
print(df.head(10))
```

but it is showing error.

```
C:\Users\Lukmana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-

packages\pandas\io\sql.py:762: UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lukmana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2023, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: ...ELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
                                                                      ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lukmana\Desktop\user_count\usercount.py", line 55, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql_table(result, dbconn)
  File "C:\Users\Lukmana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 286, in read_sql_table
    if not pandas_sql.has_table(table_name):
  File "C:\Users\Lukmana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2200, in has_table
    return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0
  File "C:\Users\Lukmana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2035, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: ...ELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
```

Comment: Which error? Without it, it is difficult to help. And `dbconn` is not defined in first case.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have added the error and code for dbconn

Comment: The first line gives you a clue: `UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy`

Comment: Note: on the reason: it seems that pandas read additionally the structure of the table (to know the types, I assume). But it use standard Python (and other language) method: using `?` as placeholder (this reduces a lot of SQL security problems (unquoted paramenters, etc.). Your db provider doesnt seem to support it, but also pandas look on `sqlite_master` table which probably will not exist.